# Removing AppBar SearchView Hint Icon

Tags: java, android, xml, searchview

I'm trying to remove the icon in the hint of my app bar search view.

[View of what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52b9S.jpg)

So i would like to remove the magnifying glass in the searchView.

I'm a beginner in android.

Here is my main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    ...

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                app:subtitleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
                app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Icons" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Recherche"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Here is my searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    />
```

And here is my Activity java

```
package com.example.test3;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        System.out.println(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
        View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
        searchPlate.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        int submitAreaId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/submit_area", null, null);
        View submitAreaView = searchView.findViewById(submitAreaId);
        submitAreaView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

I can't find out what i'm supposed to edit to remove this icon

Thank your for your answers

**EDIT** : If it's easier for you here is the github https://github.com/BenoitBonavia/geoloc-indoor-application

Answer (score 0):

Found it !
In my activity.java in the onCreateOptionsMenu method i added this :

```
int magId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
ImageView magImage = searchView.findViewById(magId);
magImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```